# Powershell Remove Static Text From File Name

Tags: powershell, foreach, rename

I'm very rusty on my Powershell. I have a folder with different types of files and I want to remove a constant string of text from each file. For example, I have 3 types of files each with the same text I want removed. But there are 300 of these in one folder.

```
file1(My Little Pony).nfo
file1(My Little Pony)-thumb.jpg
file1(My Little Pony).avi
file02(My Little Pony).nfo
file2(My Little Pony)-thumb.jpg
file002(My Little Pony).avi
```

I want to remove the text "(My Little Pony)"

It's going to be something like

```
$filepath ="C:\Folder 1"
foreach($file in $filepath){
# this is where I struggle
# rename $file take out "(My Little Pony)"
#
}
```

Comment: `file.Name -like "*(My Little Pony)*"` and `Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name.Replace("(My Little Pony"))`. But in your code example the fileName variable is just the value of the filepath variable. Use `get-childitem` to get the files

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over the **string** `"C:\Folder 1"`, but that is only the rootpath to where the files can be found.

You need to first get an array of FileInfo objects and iterate over that:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Folder 1' -Filter '*(My Little Pony)*' -File
$files | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\(My Little Pony\)'}
```

<sup>I'm using the regex `-replace` because that works Case-Insensitively as opposed to the string method `.Replace()`

By doing that, we need to **escape** the brackets `(My Little Pony)` with backslashes</sup>